# Invocablemethod Apex Class Rollup Multiple Currency Fields

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-development, salesforce-developer

I'm writing an invocablemethod batch apex class to rollup multiple currency fields on an "Order Package" object to its parent object of "Order Location". I thought I got everything added properly but it seems to be updating both the "Package_Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c" and the "Package_One_Time_Fees__c" to the same price from the Package_Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c field. Can someone help me identify why it's using the same price for both fields? Any help is much appreciated!

```
global class OrderLocationRollupSummary implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Schedulable {
    
        //Invocable Method
        @InvocableMethod(label='Rollup All Order Packages to Locations')
        global static void rollupAllorderpackages(List<Order_Location_Package__c> orderpackages) {
            rollupOrderPackages(orderpackages);
        }
    
        //Batchable Methods
        global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
            return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Order_New_Location__c]);
        }
    
        global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<sObject> batch){
            Set<Id> OrderLocationIds = new Set<Id>();
    
            for (sObject ordloc : batch) {
                OrderLocationIds.add(ordloc.Id);
            }
    
            summarizeOrderPackages(OrderLocationIds);
        }
    
        global void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {}
    
        //Schedulable Methods
        global void execute(SchedulableContext context){
            OrderLocationRollupSummary batchJob = new OrderLocationRollupSummary();
            Database.executeBatch(batchJob);
        }
    
        //Static Methods
        public static void rollupOrderPackages(List<Order_Location_Package__c> orderpackages) {
            Set<Id> OrderLocationIds = new Set<Id>();
    
            //Get Order Location Ids from specified orderpackages
            for (Order_Location_Package__c ordpckg : orderpackages) {
                OrderLocationIds.add(ordpckg.New_Location_Name__c);
            }
    
            if (OrderLocationIds.isEmpty() == false) {
                /*Execute as a future call so that the user doesn't have to wait around for
                the rollup to finish. Unless, already in a future or batch call state then
                just perform the rollup.*/
                if (System.isFuture() == false && System.isBatch() == false) {
                    summarizeOrderPackagesAsync(OrderLocationIds);
                }
                else {
                    new OrderLocationRollupSummary().summarizeOrderPackages(OrderLocationIds);
                }
            }
        }
    
        @future
        public static void summarizeOrderPackagesAsync(Set<Id> OrderLocationIds) {
            new OrderLocationRollupSummary().summarizeOrderPackages(OrderLocationIds);
        }
    
        //Public Methods
        public void summarizeOrderPackages(Set<Id> OrderLocationIds) {
            //Get Order Locations to Update
            List<Order_New_Location__c> orderlocations = queryOrderLocationsById(OrderLocationIds);
    
            Map<Id, double> results = getOrderPackagesAmountsByLocationId(OrderLocationIds);
    
            //Loop Order Locations and set Amounts
            List<Order_New_Location__c> orderlocationsToUpdate = new List<Order_New_Location__c>();
            for (Order_New_Location__c ordloc : orderlocations) {
                double mrf = 0;
                double otf = 0;
    
                if (results.containsKey(ordloc.Id)) {
                    mrf = results.get(ordloc.Id);
                    otf = results.get(ordloc.Id);
                }
    
                //Determine if Amounts have Changed
                if (ordloc.Package_Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c != mrf || 
                    ordloc.Package_One_Time_Fees__c != otf) {
                    
                    ordloc.Package_Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c = mrf;
                    ordloc.Package_One_Time_Fees__c = otf;
                    orderlocationsToUpdate.add(ordloc); //Add location to collection to be updated
                }
            }
    
            if(orderlocationsToUpdate.isEmpty() == false) {
                Database.SaveResult[] saveResults = Database.update(orderlocationsToUpdate, false);
                System.debug(saveResults);
            }
        }
    
        //Private Methods
        public Map<Id, double> getOrderPackagesAmountsByLocationId(Set<Id> OrderLocationIds) {
            Map<Id, double> resultsByOrderLocationId = new Map<Id, double>();
    
            //Summarize Order Package Amounts by Order Location Id
            AggregateResult[] results = aggregateOrderPackageAmounts(OrderLocationIds);
            for (AggregateResult result : results) {
                Id orderlocationId = (Id) result.get('OrderLocation');
                double mrf = (double) result.get('MRFees');
                double otf = (double) result.get('OTFees');
    
                resultsByOrderLocationId.put(orderlocationId, mrf);
                resultsByOrderLocationId.put(orderlocationId, otf);
            }
            return resultsByOrderLocationId;
        }
    
        //Query Methods
        private List<Order_New_Location__c> queryOrderLocationsById(Set<Id> OrderLocationIds) {
            return [SELECT 
                    Id 
                    ,Package_Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c
                    ,Package_One_Time_Fees__c
                FROM 
                    Order_New_Location__c 
                WHERE 
                    Id IN :OrderLocationIds];
        }
    
        private AggregateResult[] aggregateOrderPackageAmounts(Set<Id> OrderLocationIds) {
            return [SELECT 
                     New_Location_Name__c OrderLocation
                    ,SUM(Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c) MRFees
                    ,SUM(One_Time_Fees__c) OTFees
                FROM 
                    Order_Location_Package__c
                WHERE
                    New_Location_Name__c IN :OrderLocationIds
                GROUP BY 
                    New_Location_Name__c];
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: I'm a bit new to Apex so any help would be greatly appreciated. If there's a better way to write this, I would also be very interested. My main goal is needing to rollup multiple currency fields to a parent record but I need this to happen as close to real-time as possible, as well as update over 200 parent records at times (Order Locations). Thanks again for any guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your summarizeOrderPackages method, the following code is setting the 'mrf' and 'oft' variables to the same value.

```
        if (results.containsKey(ordloc.Id)) {
            mrf = results.get(ordloc.Id);
            otf = results.get(ordloc.Id);
        }
```

Afterwards, you are then setting the fields in question to the mrf and otf variables (which have the same value).

```
        //Determine if Amounts have Changed
        if (ordloc.Package_Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c != mrf || 
            ordloc.Package_One_Time_Fees__c != otf) {
            
            ordloc.Package_Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c = mrf;
            ordloc.Package_One_Time_Fees__c = otf;
            orderlocationsToUpdate.add(ordloc); //Add location to collection to be updated
        }
```

Consider adding a wrapper and inner class within your OrderLocationRollupSummary class to solve this problem:

```
  public class Order_New_Location_Wrapper {
    Id orderlocationId = {get;set;}
    Double mrf = {get;set;}
    Double otf = {get;set;}
    public class Order_New_Location_Wrapper (Id arg1, Double arg2, Double arg3)
    orderlocationId = arg1;
    mrf = arg2;
    otf = arg3;
  }
```

Then call this new inner class within your getOrderPackagesAmountsByLocationId method:

```
public Map<Id, Order_New_Location_Wrapper> getOrderPackagesAmountsByLocationId(Set<Id> OrderLocationIds) {

//create a list of orderlocations to represent the collection objects coming from the wrapper 
        
        resultsByOrderLocationId = new Map<Id, Order_New_Location_Wrapper>();

        //Summarize Order Package Amounts by Order Location Id
        AggregateResult[] results = aggregateOrderPackageAmounts(OrderLocationIds);
        for (AggregateResult result : results) {
            Id orderlocationId = (Id) result.get('OrderLocation');
            double mrf = (double) result.get('MRFees');
            double otf = (double) result.get('OTFees');

            resultsByOrderLocationId.add(orderlocationId, new OpportunityWrapper(orderlocationId, mrg, otf));
        }
        return resultsByOrderLocationId;
    }
```

You'll also need to update your summarizeOrderPackages method to be something like this:

```
public void summarizeOrderPackages(Set<Id> OrderLocationIds) {
    //Get Order Locations to Update
    List<Order_New_Location__c> orderlocations = queryOrderLocationsById(OrderLocationIds);

    Map<Id, Order_New_Location_Wrapper> results = getOrderPackagesAmountsByLocationId(OrderLocationIds);

    //Loop Order Locations and set Amounts
    List<Order_New_Location__c> orderlocationsToUpdate = new List<Order_New_Location__c>();
    for (Order_New_Location__c ordloc : orderlocations) {
        double mrf = 0;
        double otf = 0;

        if (results.containsKey(ordloc.Id)) {
            mrf = (Order_New_Location__c) results.get(ordloc.Id).mrf;
            otf = (Order_New_Location__c) results.get(ordloc.Id).otf;
        }

        //Determine if Amounts have Changed
        if (ordloc.Package_Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c != mrf || 
            ordloc.Package_One_Time_Fees__c != otf) {
            
            ordloc.Package_Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c = mrf;
            ordloc.Package_One_Time_Fees__c = otf;
            orderlocationsToUpdate.add(ordloc); //Add location to collection to be updated
        }
    }

    if(orderlocationsToUpdate.isEmpty() == false) {
        Database.SaveResult[] saveResults = Database.update(orderlocationsToUpdate, false);
        System.debug(saveResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm still a bit confused though, I was hoping to pull the aggregate result from the getOrderPackagesAmountsByLocationId method. How would I go about assigning the right values?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include more details on my suggestion.  I did not try to compile this, so it may not be 100% accurate, but it should provide the idea.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much! This makes sense - I'll give it a shot - Thanks again!

Comment: Is there any more guidance you could give me on the Order_New_Location_Wrapper you created? I can't seem to structure the class right to compile it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to take care of this just by updating a few of my methods, see below. Thanks again for your help Robert!

```
global class OrderLocationRollupSummary implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Schedulable {

//Invocable Method
@InvocableMethod(label='Rollup All Order Packages to Locations')
global static void rollupAllorderpackages(List<Order_Location_Package__c> orderpackages) {
    rollupOrderPackages(orderpackages);
}

//Batchable Methods
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Order_New_Location__c]);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<sObject> batch){
    Set<Id> OrderLocationIds = new Set<Id>();

    for (sObject ordloc : batch) {
        OrderLocationIds.add(ordloc.Id);
    }

    summarizeOrderPackages(OrderLocationIds);
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {}

//Schedulable Methods
global void execute(SchedulableContext context){
    OrderLocationRollupSummary batchJob = new OrderLocationRollupSummary();
    Database.executeBatch(batchJob);
}

//Static Methods
public static void rollupOrderPackages(List<Order_Location_Package__c> orderpackages) {
    Set<Id> OrderLocationIds = new Set<Id>();

    //Get Order Location Ids from specified orderpackages
    for (Order_Location_Package__c ordpckg : orderpackages) {
        OrderLocationIds.add(ordpckg.New_Location_Name__c);
    }

    if (OrderLocationIds.isEmpty() == false) {
        /*Execute as a future call so that the user doesn't have to wait around for
        the rollup to finish. Unless, already in a future or batch call state then
        just perform the rollup.*/
        if (System.isFuture() == false && System.isBatch() == false) {
            summarizeOrderPackagesAsync(OrderLocationIds);
        }
        else {
            new OrderLocationRollupSummary().summarizeOrderPackages(OrderLocationIds);
        }
    }
}

@future
public static void summarizeOrderPackagesAsync(Set<Id> OrderLocationIds) {
    new OrderLocationRollupSummary().summarizeOrderPackages(OrderLocationIds);
}

//Public Methods
public void summarizeOrderPackages(Set<Id> OrderLocationIds) {
    //Get Order Locations to Update
    List<Order_New_Location__c> orderlocations = queryOrderLocationsById(OrderLocationIds);

    Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = getOrderPackagesAmountsByLocationId(OrderLocationIds);

    //Loop Order Locations and set Amounts
    List<Order_New_Location__c> orderlocationsToUpdate = new List<Order_New_Location__c>();
    for (Order_New_Location__c ordloc : orderlocations) {
        double mrf = 0;
        double otf = 0;

        if (results.containsKey(ordloc.Id)) {
            AggregateResult ar = results.get(ordloc.Id);
            mrf = (double)ar.get('MRFees');
            otf = (double)ar.get('OTFees');
        }

        //Determine if Amounts have Changed
        if (ordloc.Package_Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c != mrf || 
            ordloc.Package_One_Time_Fees__c != otf) {
            
            ordloc.Package_Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c = mrf;
            ordloc.Package_One_Time_Fees__c = otf;
            orderlocationsToUpdate.add(ordloc); //Add location to collection to be updated
        }
    }

    if(orderlocationsToUpdate.isEmpty() == false) {
        Database.SaveResult[] saveResults = Database.update(orderlocationsToUpdate, false);
        System.debug(saveResults);
    }
}
//Private Methods
public Map<Id, AggregateResult> getOrderPackagesAmountsByLocationId(Set<Id> OrderLocationIds) {
    Map<id,AggregateResult> resultsByOrderLocationId= new Map<Id,AggregateResult>();

    //Summarize Order Package Amounts by Order Location Id
    AggregateResult[] results = aggregateOrderPackageAmounts(OrderLocationIds);
    for (AggregateResult result : results) {
        Id orderlocationId = (Id) result.get('OrderLocation');
        resultsByOrderLocationId.put(orderlocationId, result );
    }
    return resultsByOrderLocationId;
}

//Query Methods
private List<Order_New_Location__c> queryOrderLocationsById(Set<Id> OrderLocationIds) {
    return [SELECT 
            Id 
            ,Package_Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c
            ,Package_One_Time_Fees__c
        FROM 
            Order_New_Location__c 
        WHERE 
            Id IN :OrderLocationIds];
}

private AggregateResult[] aggregateOrderPackageAmounts(Set<Id> OrderLocationIds) {
    return [SELECT 
             New_Location_Name__c OrderLocation
            ,SUM(Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c) MRFees
            ,SUM(One_Time_Fees__c) OTFees
        FROM 
            Order_Location_Package__c
        WHERE
            New_Location_Name__c IN :OrderLocationIds
        GROUP BY 
            New_Location_Name__c];
}
```

}